# Fraudulent job applications with no discernible purpose. Have you ever seen them? Any idea of the motive?

Tags: job-search, recruitment, human-resources, hiring

Our company recently received two job applications into our applicant tracking system within a minute of each other.

If we had looked at either of these applications in isolation, we would have been very impressed with it, and we would certainly have done at least an initial phone screening of the candidate.

However, when we reviewed both applications in comparison to each other, it became clear to us that something hinky was going on. Further research led us to conclude that both applications were fraudulent (including fake applicant names) and submitted by the same person or people.

A lot of effort was put into these fraudulent applications. The content on the submitted résumés was detailed, relevant to our work, and impressive. Substantial effort was put into making the applications convincing. We're pretty certain that the fact that two application were submitted was an error, that in fact whoever did this only intended to submit once and made a mistake. Red flags only became obvious when the two applications were compared.

Because of the amount of effort put into this, we must assume that the person or people who did it had some real motive, but we're at a loss to determine what it is.

Have you seen anything like this at your company? Do you have any idea what the motive for it might be?

I've posted more details about this [on our information security blog](https://medium.com/@QuantopianCyber/the-case-of-the-job-applicants-who-werent-934699e99122), including copies of the two résumés that were submitted to us, but as per Stack Overflow policy, I've included above sufficient details about the question that my question here stands alone.

Comment: This is a very interesting situation, and the blog post about it was a very good read.  However, I don't think you're asking something that is addressable on Workplace SE.

Comment: "We first considered that this might be some sort of research" - seems like you already know the most likely motive. "one included a cover letter and the other didn’t" - seems like a fine topic of research (minus the arguably objectionable practice of submitting fake resumes).

Comment: "However, I don't think you're asking something that is addressable on Workplace SE."

Why not? Seems like it's reasonable to ask if other people have encountered this and were able to determine more than we were about the motive.

Comment: If it was research, then it was very stupid research, because they made the two resumes much too similar and therefore it was too obvious that something hinky was going on. Regarding the "objectionable practice of submitting fake resumes," it's not so much that we rejected to, but rather their unwillingness to come clean when called out on it. I think if you're going to do research of this sort, then the only ethical way to do it is to provide accurate contact information and come clean about what you're doing if someone figures out that it's hinky and asks.

Comment: @JonathanKamens Questions on Workplace SE are generally questions of the form "I work at a company.  I am having X problem with my company for Y reason and with Z symptoms.  How can I solve my problem?"  The respondents here are generally just regular people giving their opinions.  You are looking for a somewhat different audience, specifically other HR professionals in your locale.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57194/is-there-any-stackexchange-site-for-human-resource-qa

Comment: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic <- "Questions that lack a clear goal we can address..." I'm not sure what the goal of this question is.  Seeking information about these fake applicants in and of itself is not a goal I can suggest to you (as a contributor to Workplace SE) assistance in solving.  A suggestion I might make to make your question on-topic would be "where can I look to find people who may have had similar experiences?", but I don't think that's what you're looking for.

Comment: FWIW I do think the question and associated blog post are both interesting reads, so I'm not going to downvote the question.  I think it's a great question, but just not suitable for this format.

Comment: If you truly want to discover their possible motives, why not go along with one of them for a bit (e.g. act as if you are carrying on with the next step of the application process) and see what happens.

Comment: Too late for that, we already tipped our hand.

Comment: No, we're less than 60 people and don't hire a lot.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on " Further research led us to conclude that both applications were fraudulent"

Comment: If this question gets closed here, you might ask to have it migrated to [security.se]. They are not limited to computer security and might have some interesting insights.

Comment: Were the different resumes different genders/races/whatever?

Comment: "Could you please elaborate on " Further research led us to conclude that both applications were fraudulent"" -- There are more details in the linked article.

Comment: "Were the different resumes different genders/races/whatever?" -- No. Read the linked article.

Comment: I now feel like this question is a marketing stunt for the OP's company.

Comment: "I now feel like this question is a marketing stunt for the OP's company." *shrug* It's not. What more do you want me to say?

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar situation when I was managing a team about 20 years ago.

Half a dozen CVs each with different names, but many of the individual job details were cut/pasted and in a different order. Again, it's only obvious when you have several to compare. The names were also distinctive.

Long story short, the recruiter raged and shouted at me after I turned them all down saying they were obviously faked. I think it was a shakedown alleging illegal racism in hiring. I just ignored it and declined further calls, and never heard from them again. Having said that, I did have solid grounds to refute any such allegations.

Comment: This is what I suspected too when I read the question.  Mental illness works in mysterious ways.

Answer (score 6):

It's probably for research purposes. I've read several papers where the method used was researchers sending slightly different applications to companies and checking the results. Normally they aren't stupid enough to send them within minutes from each other, so this was a clear mistake on their side.

I wouldn't expect a malicious purpose or a fraud.

The question is what should you do if you notice the applications are too similar for two completely different people. I think you should (preferably) ignore both or, alternatively, answer to both the same way. Preferring one could skew results.

To be honest, I did something similar myself by applying with two versions of my name and with two application formats and pictures (adding a photo to your application is expected in my country). I didn't apply for the same positions and mostly not at the same companies twice obviously but the purpose was similar - it was to find out what format and name led to better results. And I did get some interesting results, which made it possible for me to optimise my application strategy.

The problem with the earlier replies ("It's a scam!") is, apart from the "scam" having a very low probability of success, that they don't explain why very similar CVs were sent to OP twice. Surely, if someone wanted to scam OP they would try to be as inconspicuous as possible and send e.g. just one or several completely different applications.

Comment: "Preferring one could skew results" - That is not your problem; that's the problem of whoever was conducting the 'research'.

Comment: Research?  I find it hard to believe that anyone would waste resources without profit being at the end.

Comment: @RichardU, that's your problem, however, isn't? If you google it you will find plenty of studies published using this methodology.

Comment: @385703 Right, because if it's on the interwebs, it must be true.  But, if that is, in fact the case, you could improve this answer with a few links to demonstrate that fact.  I suggest you do so.

Comment: Research is the first thing that came to mind for me when I read this question as well. @RichardU, here is one high profile study that I am aware of in which fake resumes were used, and I'm sure there are others.
https://scholar.harvard.edu/files/pager/files/pager_ajs.pdf

Comment: @Sander yeah, no. Two typically white male names for experimental purposes.  Ever seen a study like that before. no, it makes no sense.

Comment: preferring one over the other isn't skewing the results.  Which is preferable to employers is the result they're trying to get.

Comment: @DanNeely, yes, this would make sense for "normal" receivers of the application. But I assumed here that the OP knows the applications aren't real, which is why they aren't going to treat these applications as if they were just some random applications.

Answer (score 3):

It could be an agency trying to feel out your system and seeing if certain keywords got the right amount of attention.

I've also hear of unethical recruiting agencies using similar tactics to "crowd out" other applicants.  It's basically spamming your company in the hopes that at least one or two will get in.

From there, the scam goes something like this:

If they get a callback for an interview, they will send a very skilled, highly qualified person to do an for the interview.  Once you hire them, after a few weeks when they have learned all about your company, they will suddenly have a family emergency out of state or out of the country, and that's where the bait and switch occurs.

They will say that they can no longer continue the job, but happen to know a highly qualified person....  Another fake resume later, and a noob from a code mill who has been briefed on your company comes in and gives an interview that is stellar, thanks to good coaching.

He takes the job and is being coached over the phone by the person that left, who is now working somewhere else, and not with their sick moter/father/child/grandparent/uncle, et cet.

A variant of this one is just to stall you, send in a few stalking-horse candidates, and then, once those fakes report back, they send in someone who's been coached on your company from the recon done by the fakes,

Comment: Then why would the fake applicants fail to respond to phone calls or emails?

Comment: @Ertai87 Either they realized that they had screwed up, or the emails pointing out the similarities made them quit.  Think of how a phone scammer acts once he realizes your on to him, he just hangs up.  They know they've been busted, on to the next vitctim

Comment: @RichardU yep, if they really wanted to catch them they should have followed up like they didn't know anything. You don't ask a scammer "you're not trying to steal my identity, are you?"

Comment: We would have done that if it had occurred to us at the point when we sent the email how malicious the intent could have been. Honestly, the scenarios described above are difficult for me to imagine, and I wonder how real they are as opposed to urban legends.

Comment: @JonathanKamens Real enough to have happened at a major New York based newspaper named after a street in the financial district....  These are not urban legends, these are things I've seen first hand.

Comment: @JonathanKamens Google "Scambaiters" or look it up on YouTube some time.  You wouldn't believe it if you didn't see it.

Comment: @RichardU What is the end goal of this scam?  You explained up to the point where someone who is unqualified for the position gets the job, but then what?  Someone unqualified gets the job, then they either do a shoddy job and get fired, or are coached forever and produce value for the company.  What does the scammer get out of the scam?

Comment: Well, the recruiter gets a commission. The person coaching the employee probably gets a cut of their salary in exchange. And if the goal is industrial espionage of some sort, then they get information.

Comment: @JonathanKamens yep, and some agencies use it to make sure they get as many positions as possible.  BIG BUCKS if they can fill 10 positions with the same guy and swap him oout.

Comment: Does anyone really have the resources to send in fake applicants that actually go into interviews, and then go back and do coaching for the 'real' applicants? Spam e-mail for some kind of tactical purpose? Sure, I could see that as a possibility, but if it gets more elaborate than that, their resources will just run out before it's profitable.

Comment: The scam is improbable. The possible gain would be super small (someone works and gets paid for it) and highly uncertain (both employees can get fired immediately if they are discovered not to have the skills needed; background checks are bound to deliver evidence that will mean none of the two gets employed at all, etc. etc).

Comment: @385703 improbable or not, I've seen it first hand.  So if given a choice between believing my own eyes, or you....

Comment: @Brandin apparently they do, because they did it to a previous employer of mine.  It's most often done by a new agency trying to get a foothold in an area, but have very few quality people.  And the resources aren't that much.  One person with a computer is about all it takes.

Comment: @JonathanKamens, no, if you have a solid contract with the recruiting agency, they won't get a commission in this type of situation since their commission is dependant on the employee's staying with the company and/or on the employee's data being correct. If you don't, you shouldn't use agencies anyway. Not to mention that normally people's credentials get checked before the employment, which prevents you from employing people with fake histories and/or skills.

Comment: @385703 How many years of experience in the industry are you basing this claim on?  Can you provide some statistics as to what "normally" means?  I've been consulting for 30 years now, and most times nobody did any serious background check, other than for criminal records.  What do you base your claim on?

Answer (score 2):

This could be the first step in CEO fraud as well (or maybe HR fraud in this case?).

They try to get you to communicate with them to analyze your speech patterns and usual wording, as well as the composition of your company's mails. Then they send their own mail to one of your co-workers that looks exactly like what you would write and like it's sent from your account.

They either instruct your co-worker to click on a link to a virus or  to pay some money to some bank account without telling anyone for some obscure reasons.

I witnessed this kind of attack once and it's very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I heard about a similar observed pattern where the general conclusion was that it was an attempt at placing profiles for corporate espionage.